# Derivative of softmax with random loss function

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, mathematical-statistics

I am having trouble understanding the derivative of the softmax with respect to loss function.I will try to explain my understanding with one example. Suppose we have vector of 3 values and we want to compute softmax **[a1 = 5, a2 = 3, a3 = 2]**. The output is vector again with size 3 and all the values should sum up to 1.
Output = **[ o1 = 0.84, o2 = 0.11, o3 = 0.05]**. This is because of the formula of softmax which is normalized by the sum of all the exp of the input. Softmax formula: 
[image]

This gives the output for the first value of the output vector o1 = 0.84. Now suppose we have a random loss function lets call it **L** , which again outputs vector with values **[ y1, y2, y3 ]**. The output from the softmax will be supplied as input to the **L** function.
So what is the derivative of the softmax with respect to L. Lets take for simplicity **a1** we want to find the derivative of a1 with respect to the **L** function :

[image]

This is the equation using the chain rule, and now substitute the derivative of o1 with respect with a1 we end up with :
[image]

Are my calculations correct or i am missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So what is the derivative of the softmax with respect to L.

Normally, the loss function used in neural networks is a scalar, which is why we work with partial derivatives ($L:\mathbb R^n \mapsto  \mathbb R^1$).

If you have a vector valued input to a loss function and a vector valued output ($L:\mathbb R^n \mapsto  \mathbb R^m$), first-order derivatives are summarized in a Jacobian matrix.

Let's assume you have a loss function that produces a vector. In this case, your derivative calculation would make sense only if $a_1$ is not used in the calculation of $y_2$ and $y_3$. Otherwise, for each parameter (e.g. $a_1$), you end up with a Jacobian as opposed to a partial derivative. How to update parameters using a vector-valued derivative is unclear, as you are now trying to optimize for *multiple* different outcomes. This is not to say that we don't do this, in fact, multi-task learning does exactly this. As it turns out, there is a whole lot of research on this topic alone. Check out [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.07115) for example. Other friendly and more accessible introduction to this setting are [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/deep-multi-task-learning-3-lessons-learned-7d0193d71fd6) and [here](https://ruder.io/multi-task/).

Comment: So the derivative is wrong because actually **a1** influences **o2** and **o3** (the dependence come from the denominator in the softmax formula). In order to be right i should sum up the derivative of **o2** with respect to **a1** and **o3** with respect to **a1** again just to get the whole partial derivative of **Loss** with respect to **a1** , right ? Sorry for the stupid question.